# How can i read NamedTemporaryFile in python.?

Tags: python

I am new to python2.6 programming,my goal is to create .txt or .xls "temporary file" in temp directory of os and write some data to it.and then read the data from "temporary file", after completion of reading data,remove "temporary file" from temp directory.

for that process i choose NamedTemporaryFile(),but can't achieved.
Could you suggest how can i achieve it.Thanks in advance.

```
>>> import os
>>> import tempfile
>>> with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
            print temp.name
            temp.write('Some data')            
            f = open(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),temp.name))
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.close()
            temp.flush()


c:\users\110\appdata\local\temp\tmpf8p3kc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 4, in <module>
    f = open(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),temp.name))
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\110\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpf8p3kc'
```

Answer (score 13):

The approach I've used is to use `file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(..., delete=False)`, to close the resulting file after I'm done writing to it, and to manually call `os.remove(file.name)` when I'm done. (You can do the file removal in the `__exit__` method of [a custom context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) to make this nicer to use with `with`.)

Comment: What's the benefit of using a NamedTemporaryFile if you set `delete=False`?

Comment: @MattIanHong There are other benefits to use `NamedTemporaryFile` other than automatic deletion.   By default it will be put within a temporary directory, and the filename is automatically generated to not collide with existing files and without race conditions.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem once..

From the documentation: "Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later)."

Why don't you just try to read from the file using the `temp` object when it's still open? If it's open with `w+b` mode then you should be able to seek() and read()

Comment: In general, it might not always be possible to "just try to read from the file".  In the case where I ran into this problem, I was writing to a temporary file that later was fed to a different program, and that other program (over which I have no control) expected to be able to open the specified file.

Answer (score -1):

I've created an alternate mechanism which creates a named temporary file but does not keep it open. It is thus completely useable anywhere. Instead of deleting on close it deletes at the end of the `with` block.

Install the [shelljob](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shelljob) pip package. Example usage from the [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/shelljob/shelljob.fs.NamedTempFile-class.html):

```
with fs.NamedTempFile() as nm:
    proc.call( "curl http://mortoray.com/ -o {}".format( nm ) )
    html = open(nm).read()
    print( len(html) )
```